# Is TcpClient BeginRead/Send thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, tcpclient, networkstream

Using a .NET `TcpClient` if I have called an asynchronous `BeginRead()` on the associated network stream can I still call `Write()` on that stream on another thread?

Or do I have to `lock()` the `TcpClient` in the code that is called back from the `BeginRead` and the code that does the send?

Also if I close the `TcpClient` with:

```
client.GetStream().Close();
client.Close();
```

Do I have to `lock()` on the `TcpClient` as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The read/write portions of the `TcpClient` are thread safe, as explained in the documentation for the `NetworkStream` class (which is what the `TcpClient` uses for its actual IO):

> Read and write operations can be
>   performed simultaneously on an
>   instance of the NetworkStream  class
>   without the need for synchronization.
>   As long as there is one unique thread
>   for the write operations and one
>   unique thread for the read operations,
>   there will be no cross-interference
>   between read and write threads and no
>   synchronization is required.

To do with the closing, if you close the `TcpClient` on one thread, but then try to read/write using it on another thread after it is closed, an exception will be thrown.  You can either synchronise the threads before it is closed in order to prevent them using the `TcpClient`, or just catch and handle the exception (for example, you might exit the thread's executing loop).

Comment: Thank you I completely missed that in MSDN my bad - I apologise.

On the close I am catching and handling the exception but just wasn't sure if that was dodgy so thanks for clarifying that is ok as that isn't documented as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yeah, it's perfectly normal for it to throw an exception if you try to write to / read from a TcpClient that has been closed. You'll see that across all of the .NET socket APIs.